# php multiplying int by decimal produces an int?

Tags: php, int, decimal, multiplication

So I'm trying to understand this behaviour:
In my database table, I have a row quantity (int 11) and a column price (decimal 5,2).
Multiplying them to get a total, outputs an integer... how's this possible?

```
$qty = 2;
$price = 10;
$total = $qty * $price;

echo "$total";
```

// Outputs 20. Shouldn't it output 20,00?

Comment: First, are you sure `$qty` and `$price` are int and float types in PHP? Try to var_dump them and check the types there. Depending on how you set up your connection and fetched them, they may not be the same types that they are in MySQL.

Comment: Second, even if `$total` is a float, just echoing it will not show trailing zeroes after the decimal. (Try `echo 20.00;` for a simple example. You'll see `20`.) You'll need to use a formatting function to show the number of decimals you want.

Comment: var_dump showed they are both string types. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone else wondering, there's a php currency formatting function.
http://php.net/manual/it/function.money-format.php
Check the manual for further informations, thanks for the ones that answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have not proven anything.  20 is the correct *value*.

```
$qty = 2;
$price = 10.23;
$total = $qty * $price;
echo "$total";
```

Gives `20.46`, again the correct *value*.

If you want to *format* the output, use

```
printf("%.2f", $total);
```

to get results like

```
20.00
20.46
```

To adjust for locale, `money_format()` would be better.  This would get you the `,` (or whatever) instead of `.`